# How to get constraint layout height which is set as wrap_content?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

How can I get the `error_layout` of constraint layout height? I need to set margin-bottom for one more layout `result_layout` by leaving space for the `error_layout` view below.
I have separate it out into two layouts to animate each one after the other.

Tried with this. But it's giving the wrong calculation.

```
private void getViewHeight(final ConstraintLayout layout) {
        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                layout_height_margin = layout.getHeight();
            }
        });
    }
```

call `getViewHeight(error_layout)` after view created.

```
constraintSet.connect(result_layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, layout_height_margin);
// Expecting the exact value of error_layout height to set margin value.
```

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BEE">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_layout"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_layout"
        ...
     >
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Animate layout:

```
private void animateResult(ConstraintLayout constraint, Boolean show, int margin, int delay) {
        final ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(root_layout);
        constraintSet.clear(constraint.getId(), show ? ConstraintSet.TOP : constraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(constraint.getId(), show ? ConstraintSet.BOTTOM : ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, margin);

        final Transition transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(1.0f));
        transition.setDuration(1200);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root_layout, transition);
                constraintSet.applyTo(root_layout);
            }
        }, delay);

    }
```

Comment: I exactly did not understand the question, But android:layout_width seems to be missing for error_layout and in general you can get height with post method or using global tree listener and by fetching layout params, But you need to get margins also since that will also have an effect If this is what you are looking for kindly comment so I can post code.

Comment: Found the actual issue. when I try to animate this, first animate is disappearing from viewport. Any idea how to animate both?

```animateResult(result_layout, true, layout_height_margin, 0);
animateResult(error_layout, true, 12, 0);```

Comment: what kind of animation do you want? Can you explain more?

Comment: First setting the view constraint as hidden under bottom of the layout and then translate up (refer: animate func above). When animate the same time for both layout, first one disappeared.

Comment: So first  constraintSet.applyTo(root_layout); -> do this before beginDelayedTransition and see if its working.Also, any reason why you are using handler there and applying it after delay?